# Inner loop in loop with combination th:field in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am making web app using Java/Spring/Thymeleaf and have problem to view data of HashMaps in list using th:field. I have classes:

```
public class CompleteMeasurementResult {    
    private List<MeasurementResult> measurementResults;

// getter, setter, constructor
}

`public class MeasurementResult{
    private Map<Long, SurfaceResult> groupedSurfaceResultByTaskType;

// getter, setter, constructor
}`

public class SurfaceResult  {
    private Double timeDuration;

    // getter, setter, constructor
}
```

and template, where completeMeasurementResult is in th:object

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/reCountMeasurement}" th:object="${completeMeasurementResult}" method="post">
<table class="measurementResults">
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="measurementResult, measurementResultStat : *{measurementResults}"

        <div th:each="surface, surfaceStat : *{measurementResults[__${measurementResultStat.index}__].groupedSurfaceResultByTaskType}">
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{measurementResults[__${measurementResultStat.index}__].groupedSurfaceResultByTaskType[__${surfaceStat.index}__].timeDuration}" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The exception follows

```
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "mixedChart": null
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1442)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1476)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1474)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:276)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.CloseElementTag.beHandled(CloseElementTag.java:139)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
```

I am new in Thymeleaf and really appreciate any solution.
Thank you, Petr.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem by changing structure of MeasurementResult where I replaced 
private Map groupedSurfaceResultByTaskType;
by 
private List groupedSurfaceResultByTaskType;

than in Thymeleaf template 
*{measurementResults[**${measurementResultStat.index}**].groupedSurfaceResultByTaskType[**${surfaceStat.index}**].timeDuration}
will working.